# How to create a C++ button with an icon

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make a custom exit button, and I have already created a custom graphic for the button in photoshop.  I have the button as defined by this code:

```
button = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILDWINDOW, 400, 4, 480, 24, hWnd, button_id, hInstance, NULL);
```

I want to put either `close.bmp` or `close.png` or `close.ico` (whichever's easiest) onto the button, however I cannot find a way to do this without MFC.  Please help!!!

Thanks

Comment: I did this once long ago using `BitBlt`. I have no idea if this is a reasonable way to do it. Maybe it will help. https://github.com/ezod/minimine/blob/master/src/minimine.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`BS_BITMAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`BS_ICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) button styles.  After creating the button, send it a [`BM_SETIMAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message with the handle to your bitmap or icon.  To get the handle to your bitmap or icon, use [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If your image has an alpha channel (transparency), make sure it's saved as a 32-bit-per-pixel bitmap.  You can get by with an icon, but the edges probably won't be as smooth.

Comment: Using Code::Blocks 17.02 with gcc on Windows 7, I had to add a manifest file + I had to reference commctrl.h to make this work (text + image on a button).  I found I had more control using BS_OWNERDRAW instead of the method described here.

Comment: @Ken_sf:  The manifest file was probably to enable "visual styles."  They're not enabled by default for backward compatibility.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview

Answer (score 3):

There are two main possibilities:

1. If you only want to **put a bitmap on a regular button**, then create the button with the `WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_PUSHBUTTON|BS_BITMAP` style combination, load the bitmap using `LoadBitmap`, and put the loaded bitmap on the button by sending its handle to the button in a `BM_SETIMAGE` message.
2. If you want to **change the appearance of the whole button**, then create it with the `WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_OWNERDRAW` style combination, and handle the `WM_DRAWITEM` message. Cast the `lParam` of this message to an `LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT`, and use its `hDC` member to draw the button. In your case, preload the bitmap using `LoadBitmap`, and draw it on the DC using `BitBlt` or `TransparentBlt` ([source](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html)). Alternatively, you can use `LoadIcon` and `DrawIconEx` ([source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19913/Owner-draw-icon-buttons-in-plain-C-no-MFC)). Other members of the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` can be used to select the bitmap, that is, the appearance of the button, depending on current action or state.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky...

Your best option is to use a Owner-Draw button, that is with the style bit `BS_OWNERDRAW`.

Then, the *owner* of the button (the parent window) will receive the message `WM_DRAWITEM` whenever the button is to be redrawn.

The drawback is that the button has to be painted fully, not only the icon, but also the frame, the background, the label if required, the focus rectangle... You have to check the associated `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` and decide the exact style to be drawn.

To ease the work it can be useful the Windows function `DrawFrameControl()` that paints several styles of frames, including the standard button frame.

Comment: This is a possible route, and it's useful if you have complex drawing requirements, but it's probably more work than using BS_ICON or BS_BITMAP for simply adding an image.  Be aware that DrawFrameControl draws old-fashioned button frames (pre-Windows XP themes), which can look out-of-place on a modern application.

Answer (score 1):

send **BM_SETIMAGE** message, and pass loaded image handle to lParam.

```
button1 = CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", L"&Button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | BS_BITMAP, 20, 50, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 600, NULL, NULL);

hImg = LoadImageW(NULL, L"test123.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SendMessageW(button1, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) hImg);
```

P.S: you need to use **BS_BITMAP** flag when CreateWindow()