# How can I force to work the alpha-channel in RGBA image on window background?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I'm setting a background:

```
WindowClass.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush((HBITMAP)LoadImageA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(TEST), IMAGE_BITMAP, 120, 120, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION));
```

(similar code works well for tray-menu icons - the alpha on images works)

After registering a class I'm creating a window:

```
CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOPMOST, WindowClass.lpszClassName, ApplicationTitleA.c_str(), WS_POPUP, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - AW_WIDTH) / 2, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - AW_HEIGHT) / 2, AW_WIDTH, AW_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

But there is a black brush instead of transparency:

[image: test_alpha]

So, the main question is in the topic's header :)

Comment: Icons aren't bitmaps. Bitmaps aren't icons.

Comment: @IInspectable, of course, but I used the same bmp images (RGBA) for those icons. For example `MENUITEMINFOW ExitBtnII; ... ExitBtnII.hbmpItem = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(EXITBMP), IMAGE_BITMAP, 24, 24, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)`

Comment: Very few GDI functions support alpha channels. The icon rendering code is specifically written with alpha blending implemented. Window background rendering, on the other hand, is not. You'll have to handle the [WM_ERASEBKGND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055.aspx) message yourself, and [AlphaBlend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351.aspx) the 32bpp bitmap to get the desired result.

Comment: The simplest way is to use a static control with the `SS_BITMAP` style. Slightly more complex is a layered child window. [Both methods support bitmaps with alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603066/7571258).

Comment: @zett42, thanks for useful info! Is it works with buttons to?

Comment: [How to create a C++ button with an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13461653/7571258)

Comment: @zett42, I already tested in on button with `BS_BITMAP` style and with manifest - rgba loads with transparency! Also the `WS_POPUP` style makes a parent window transparent, so I can use a static control with alpha image as a layer to achieve my goal. Thank you for advice again! If you will write an answer I'll accept it